# Python script does not work under crontab

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a very basic python script to run through crontab for every minutes.

The Script

```
filed = open('test.txt','a')
```

Crontab

```
* * * * * /to path the file/job.py
```

It should work, but i have not been able to see the results. So, what could be the problem ?

Comment: [@MartijnPieters is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14573308/418413), but doesn't your cron send you emails when it fails? What do those emails say?

Comment: Usually these problems are because the env for your shell is different to cron. It can be the pwd as Martijn says. Another possibility would be your `$PATH` is different. You need to give us some more clues to work out the actual problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to open `text.txt` using an absolute path; the crondaemon may well be using different path from what you expect:

```
filed = open('/home/john/Desktop/test.txt','a')
```

Comment: +1 More flexible may be the following: `import os; filed = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.txt'), 'a')`, which basically does what you do, but creates absolute path by building it dynamically for the file located in the same directory as Python script.